# Knockoutjs and Jquery draggable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have an observable array that I add or remove elements to. The elements are displayed as DIVs.
I want to make each DIV draggable, however because the DIV is created on the fly I am not sure how to do this. I was thinking of using the JQuery live() function, but I need to pass and action, so I dont think this would be the right approach.

This is my code:
Knockout:

```
function AssetViewModel() {


var self = this;

self.assets = ko.observableArray([]);

self.addAsset = function(){
    self.assets.push(
        {
            id: "1",
            content: "Hello World",
            type: "Asset"
        }
    );
}
self.removeAsset = function(asset){
    self.assets.remove(asset);
    };
};
```

HTML:

```
<div id="layer1" data-bind="foreach: assets">
<div data-bind="text: content" class="asset"></div>

</div>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for [custom bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).  The gist is you create your own binding so you markup looks like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: assets">
    <div data-bind="draggable: $data">
        <p>More markup</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The custom binding would be:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.draggable = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, vieModel, bindingContext){
        $(element).draggable();
        return ko.bindingHandlers.with.init.apply(this, arguments);
    }
};
```

You don't need to return anything but by calling the `with` binding init function, you create a wrapper binding that performs your logic and and acts like the binding you're returning.  It's generally a good place to start when learning custom bindings.

Comment: Worked like a charm! But it I had to make one change, it shouldn't be a function.

Comment: Right you are!  Not sure how I missed that, good catch.  I updated the answer.  Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read next article - [Revisiting Dragging, Dropping, and Sorting observableArrays](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/02/revisiting-dragging-dropping-and.html)
It contains detailed explanation and number of samples.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure whether you just want to add sorting within your layer1 div (or dragging and dropping amongst other dom elements.) Regardless of what you want I'd use the Knockout-Sortable plugin (https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable).

It worked for me on a complex sort, drag and drop solution with Knockout (named templates nested multiple layers.)

Check the JSFiddles at the bottom of that page to get started.

Hope that helps.